# For what values of $B$ does $ADB + (ADB)^T$ have positive eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given real, non-square, matrices $A$ and $B$, and a diagonal, square, full rank, positive matrix $D$, under what conditions for $B$ does the quantity $ADB + (ADB)^T$ have positive  eigenvalues such that $B$ does not depend on $D$?

If necessary, $D$ has entries that are upper bounded by some constant.

$B=A^T$ is one condition, but I suspect it's not the only one and I'm not sure how to go about it. Ideally, we can avoid any dependence on $D$. If $A^T$ is the only solution, how can I prove this?

The lines of attack I have tried but couldn't take very far are:

- Conditions on $B$ that make $ADB$ symmetric with positive eigenvalues (i.e positive semi-definite)
- Conditions on $B$ that make $ADB$ a "normal" matrix (i.e commutes with it's transpose) and also has positive eigenvalues. This would work since the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices is the product of the eigenvalues if the two matrices commute with each other.

The problem that underlies this question is a dynamical system I am conditioning for stability. $D$ is a diagonal matrix of first derivatives of a monotonic function that can be bounded, $A$ and $B$ are parameters/weight matricies tha also can be bounded. I am searching on how to condition $B$ such that $x^TADBx \geq 0$, of which a positive semi-definite $ADB + (ADB)^T$ is a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C=B^T$. Since
$$
ADC^T+(ADC^T)^T=\sum_j d_{jj}(\mathbf a_j\mathbf c_j^T+\mathbf c_j\mathbf a_j^T),
$$
if it is positive definite for *every* positive diagonal matrix $D$, then $\mathbf a_j\mathbf c_j^T+\mathbf c_j\mathbf a_j^T$ must be positive semidefinite. Therefore, either

- $\mathbf a_j=0$,
- $\mathbf c_j=0$, or
- $\mathbf c_j$ is a positive multiple of $\mathbf a_j$.

In particular, if all columns of $A$ and $C$ are nonzero, we must have $C=AS$ (i.e. $B=SA^T$) for some positive diagonal matrix $S$. If $A$ and $C$ also have full row ranks, this condition would be sufficient too.

Comment: this is really great, thank you! Would you mind explaining your statement "if it is positive definite for every positive diagonal matrix DD, then $a_jc^T_j+c_ja^T_j$ must be positive semidefinite" a little bit more? How do we know this, and is this an if-and-only-if condition?

Comment: Also, provided that $a_j \neq 0$ is the condition that $C = AS$ necessary, or just sufficient?

Comment: @Robert (1) Let $d_{jj}=1$ and let all other $d_{jj}$ approaches 0. Hence $a_jc_j^T+c_ja_j^T$ is positive semidefinite. (2) The whole derivation shows that the either-or condition (about the three bullet points) is necessary. It is surely not sufficient (consider, e.g. $A=C=\pmatrix{1\\ 1}$ or $A=C=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0}$. The either-or condition is satisfied, but $ADC^T+CDA^T=2ADA^T$ is singular). When $A,C$ have no zero columns and $C=AS$ for some positive diagonal matrix $S$, we get $ADC^T+CDA^T=2A(DS)A^T$. Hence it is positive definite if and only if $A$ has full row rank.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, let's say $A = C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then $ADC^T + CDA^T$ will be singular -- but because the conditions are satisfied, we are certain that $ADC^T + CDA^T$ is positive semi-definite. Right?

Likewise, because the conditions are necessary for positive-semi-definiteness (with an extra one for positive definiteness) , if the conditions were *not* satisfied, we are sure that $ADC^T + CDA^T$ is definitively not positive definite or positive semi-definite. Right?

Comment: @Robert If for some $j$, neither of the three bullet points is satisfied, then $ADC^T+CDA^T$ is not positive semidefinite, and hence also not positive definite. If, for every $j$, at least one of the three bullet points are satisfied, then $ADC^T+CDA^T$ is positive semidefinite, but it may fail to be positive definite because it can be singular.

Comment: This is great - thank you so much! I've accepted the answer and rewarded the bounty. If I waned to consider the conditions on $B$ if we restrict the maximum magnitudes of the $A$ and $D$ matrices, and the maximum $x$ for which positive semi-definiteness is being considered, are there any ideas/concepts that you think I should know/study?

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if a matrix is positive definite, its positive multiples are positive definite too. So, I don't see how the "magnitudes" (regardless of how you measure them) of $A$ and $D$ are relevant.

Comment: I guess I thought that if the maximum $d_{jj}$ was specified, and bounds were placed elementwise on $x$ (and potentially on $a_{ij}$ as well, although it sounds like that might not be necessary), we might be able to specify a looser condition on $C = f(A)$ for which $0 \leq x^TADC^Tx$.

Comment: @Robert This is still irrelevant. Even if you put an elementwise bound on $x$, the direction that $x$ points to is still free. And you cannot impose any limit on the direction of $x$ in the definition of positive definiteness in the first place.